# create stream from string directly

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

We can create stream from List of string like this

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("somestring");
    Stream<String> stream = list.stream();
```

But how to create stream directly from string.

```
String x = "somestring";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Stream.of](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T-) which returns a sequential Stream containing a single element.

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `Stream.of("somestring")`